# How to give path to the PDF file while creation in struts 2?

Tags: java, file-io, struts2

I am trying to create a PDF file using struts 2.Action class location is as follows.

```
/home/Jagan/MATCH/Jagan/src/ActionClasses/PDFFile.java
```

Here workspace starts from

> /MATCH

In PDFFile.java.I am writing as given below and it is working fine.

> pdfwriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new
>   FileOutputStream("/home/Jagan/xyz.pdf"));

But i have to create this under the folder

> /home/Jagan/MATCH/Jagan/PDFs

I should not use `/home/Jagan/` as it will become hardcode if i have to run this application in other system.

I tried

> pdfwriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new
>   FileOutputStream("../../../PDFs/xyz.pdf"));

But it is not creating file.Even if it works it is not feasible  solution (because "../../../" does not work in windows ).

Please suggest me a good way to specify path for creating file.

---

Adding to the question.

I have to provide download option for downloading this created file in JSP page.Which struts tag should i use. Please provide me syntax for that

Comment: Finally got it.An easy example for file download. http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-download-file-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downloading files has 2 aproaches:
1. you can return it with outstream result like is explained [here](http://www.snakedj.ch/2007/12/27/struts2-file-download/)
2. as you are trying to save the file first at filesystem then access it from another url.
     Answer to your question is you should get servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF"), and after that everything is relative to WEB-INF.

Comment: 2. as you are trying to save the file first at filesystem then access it from another url. Please provide me syntax. I am struck.

Comment: your action should implement ServletRequestAware. then add folowing method and I supose you can handle from there: public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {
  String fileDir="/files/pdf";//directory where all files are created and located
  String fileName="test.pdf";//file name of generated pdf
  File f=new File(req.getRealPath("/WEB-INF")+fileDir+fileName);
  //..... you can do whatever you want with the files
 }

Comment: req.getRealPath("/WEB-INF") is returning "/home/Jagan/MATCH/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Jagan/WEB-INF"

Comment: it returns absolute path where is web-inf, whenever application  is deployed, so you create folder relative to web-inf and you'll don't have problems.

Comment: File creation is done.I stored realpath in "String s" in the action class and Provided getS() getter to get path value in Jsp.Which Struts tag should i use to make it downloadable?

Comment: Above example is for dynamic file download.I am storing file in filesystem.I tried <S:href value="%{s}" >Download</s> but it is not working.(s has path to PDF file )

Comment: @Zemzela let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1571/discussion-between-jagan-and-zemzela)

Comment: Be advised that `ServletContext.getRealPath()` will return null if your app is running from an unexploded war file.

Answer (score 1):

> I should not use /home/Jagan/ as it will become hardcode if i have to run this application in other system.

Correct, Use following instead

```
System.getProperty("user.home");///home/Jagan/, it will return you path to your home dir
```

Comment: But what if i  change location of my workspace to /home/Jagan/Downloads/MATCH. Irrespective of workspace location application should create PDF file under "PDFs" directory.

Comment: well if you give it absolute path it will create it for sure

Comment: Without giving absolute path i have to create file.So i tried pdfwriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("../../../PDFs/xyz.pdf")); But it is not creating.

Comment: any exception ?,but why don't you choose the first approach ?

Comment: Portability.What someone tries run this application by placing workspace under some other directories one have to change the path right.and "../../../" is not good idea because it works only unix.What about if we want to run in windows again we have to change the syntax.

Comment: you can use `File.separator `

Comment: @JigarJoshi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1570/discussion-between-jagan-and-jigar-joshi)

Comment: Use a property file to read the location of the pdf file. And use `system.getPrperty("myHome")` to get location of your property file. you can change the `myHome` location by editing `run.bat` of the server